# PowerShell script to purge message queues is not working

Tags: powershell

I have downloaded a script from the PowerShell gallery that is supposed to purge message queues in RabbitMQ. However, I am getting some errors that I cannot fix. So my script is like so:

```
function Clear-RabbitMQQueue
{
[CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess=$false, ConfirmImpact="High")]
Param
(
    # Name of RabbitMQ Virtual Host.
    [parameter(Mandatory=$false, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true, Position=0)]
    [Alias("test_test", "vhost")]
    [string]$VirtualHost = $defaultVirtualHost,

    # The name of the queue from which to receive messages
    [parameter(Mandatory=$false, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true, Position=1)]
    [Alias("test_Test", "QueueName")]
    [string]$Name,

    # Name of the computer hosting RabbitMQ server. Defalut value is localhost.
    [parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true, Position=2)]
    [Alias("test_servername", "HostName")]
    [string]$BaseUri,

    # Credentials to use when logging to RabbitMQ server.
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
    [PSCredential]$Credentials
)

Begin
{
}
Process
{
    if ($pscmdlet.ShouldProcess("server: $BaseUri/$VirtualHost", "purge queue $Name"))
    {
        $url = Join-Path $BaseUri "/#/queues/$([System.Web.HttpUtility]::UrlEncode($VirtualHost))/$([System.Web.HttpUtility]::UrlEncode($Name))"
        Write-Verbose "Invoking REST API: $url"

        $result = Invoke-RestMethod $url -Credential $Credentials -AllowEscapedDotsAndSlashes -DisableKeepAlive -ErrorAction Continue -Method Delete
    }
}
End
{
}
}

Clear-RabbitMQQueue
```

And the error I am getting is:

```
  Join-Path : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is an empty string.
  At C:\Git Repository\Rabbit\Clear-RabbitMQQueue.ps1:33 char:30
  +             $url = Join-Path $BaseUri "/#/queues/$([System.Web.HttpUt ...
  +                              ~~~~~~~~
  + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Join-Path], 
  ParameterBindingValidationException
  + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorEmptyStringNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.JoinPathCommand

Invoke-RestMethod : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Uri'. The argument 
is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not 
null or empty, and then try the command again.
At C:\Git Repository\Rabbit\Clear-RabbitMQQueue.ps1:36 char:41
+             $result = Invoke-RestMethod $url -Credential $Credentials ...
+                                         ~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Invoke-RestMethod], 
ParameterBindingValidationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand
```

Please can someone help me fix these errors? It's urgent!

**UPDATE**

New code:

```
Function Clear-RabbitMQQueue()
{

-virtualHost CCS_Loans2Go_DEV -Name computershare.infiniti.integration.test.Computershare.Infiniti.FormProcessing.Contracts:IFormSubmittedEvent.FormPrimedEvent.event -HostName rabbitmq-dev.emea.cshare.net

}

Clear-RabbitMQQueue
```

Error I'm getting is:

```
-virtualHost : The term '-virtualHost' is not recognized as the name of a 
cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check 
the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is 
correct and try again.
At line:4 char:5
+     -virtualHost CCS_Loans2Go_DEV -Name computershare.infiniti.integr ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (-virtualHost:String) [], 
CommandNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Comment: You haven't supplied any parameters to `Clear-RabbitMQQueue` so `$BaseUri` is blank.  Look at the [examples](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/RabbitMQTools/1.5.1/Content/Public%5CClear-RabbitMQQueue.ps1) - e.g. `Clear-RabbitMQQueue vh1 q1`  *"Removes all messages from queue "q1" in Virtual Host "vh1" on local computer."*

Comment: Thank you for your response. So how would I amend it?

Comment: Why not install modules as in the [documentation](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/RabbitMQTools/1.5.1)?  That is with `Install-Module -Name RabbitMQTools`.  Then you can just use `Clear-RabbitMQQueue -VirtualHost vh1 -Name q1 -HostName rabbitmq.server.com` replacing the queue details with what you want to clear.  Only **you** know what queue you want to clear.

Comment: Please update your question rather than post errors in comments - it is too hard to read.  Have a look at this question though : [Unable to find type System.Web.HttpUtility in PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38408729/unable-to-find-type-system-web-httputility-in-powershell)

Comment: I have updated the question.